# NotificationCenter : -[NSRunLoop ]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: cocoa, selector, nsnotificationcenter

i'm new to Cocoa and I'm having a little trouble with a sample app i'm writing :

```
@implementation DeviceDetection    
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
        [notCenter addObserver:self
                      selector:@selector(discMounted:)
                          name:@"NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification" 
                        object:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]]; // Register for all notifications
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)discMounted:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"COUCOU");
}    
@end



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DeviceDetection : NSObject {

    NSNotificationCenter *notCenter;

}

- (void) discMounted:(NSNotification *)notification;


@end




@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    DeviceDetection* d = [[DeviceDetection alloc] init];

    [d value];
} 
@end
```

With that piece of code i'm getting a the following error when I plug-in a USB drive :

```
[NSRunLoop discMounted:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10054c5a0
```

Any reason why ?

Thx

Comment: try running with NSZombieEnabled, seems like you are releasing some object which is still in use. Also where you have released the observer.

Comment: With NSZombieEnabled I get `[DeviceDetection discMounted:]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Comment: where you have released the observer?

Comment: Nowhere. All I have is `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    DeviceDetection* d = [[DeviceDetection alloc] init];` In my AppDelegate.

Comment: can you show code of DeviceDetection class?

Comment: I edited the post. There's all the code I have. Ps : I use automatic reference counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `dealloc` method of `DeviceDetection`-

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

EDIT 1 -

```
DrivesOnDock[5207:707] -[DeviceDetection value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100475b40 when the app starts.
```

Above error occurs because you haven't defined `value` in `DeviceDetection` class.

Comment: With ARC (Automatic reference counting) I don't need `[super dealloc]`. But thanks it solves my problem. discMounted is called when I plug-in my usb drive. But I still get `DrivesOnDock[5207:707] -[DeviceDetection value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100475b40` when the app starts. Any idea why ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - Thanks for correcting me, i am not much used to ARC till now :)

Comment: Why is a value method needed ?

Comment: because you are calling - [d value];. Is this method is some library defined method?

Comment: -_- I'm really dumb sometimes.

Comment: Hum, If I remove this method call, my DeviceDetection object gets deallocated. I've to learn more about ARC ...

Comment: After a quick google search. I moved `DeviceDetection* d;` to the interface and it solves all my problems. A big thank you!